# Connection to bastion host closed after successful authentication

Tags: ssh, openssh, amazon-linux

I am struggling to figure out what is wrong with my bastion host configuration. I am using amazon linux 2 and when I try sshing with ec2-user everything works fine. If you use another user, it simply authenticates and drops the connection.

```
ssh -i key1 ec2-user@54.246.75.30 # works
ssh -i key2 mcuber@54.246.75.30 # doesn't work
```

I have tried removing .bashrc and .bash_profile for mcuber user but no luck.

When running ssh command with (-vvv), I am getting the following:

```
Authenticated to 54.246.75.30 ([54.246.75.30]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri Aug 28 09:29:09 2020 from 176.248.228.210

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 54.246.75.30 closed.
Transferred: sent 3912, received 3196 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 77298.5, received 63150.8
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Could someone advise what would be the next step to debug this or provide more light on what the potential issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after analysing the userdata used by the bastion host I finally found the cause of the issue.

```
while read line; do
  USER_NAME="`get_user_name "$line"`"

  # Make sure the user name is alphanumeric
  if [[ "$USER_NAME" =~ ^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$ ]]; then

    # Create a user account if it does not already exist
    cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -qx $USER_NAME
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
      /usr/sbin/adduser $USER_NAME && \
      usermod -s /bin/false $USER_NAME && \
      mkdir -m 700 /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh && \
      chown $USER_NAME:$USER_NAME /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh && \
      echo "$line" >> ~/keys_installed && \
      echo "`date --date="today" "+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"`: Creating user account for $USER_NAME ($line)" >> $LOG_FILE
    fi

    # Copy the public key from S3, if a user account was created
    # from this key
    if [ -f ~/keys_installed ]; then
      grep -qx "$line" ~/keys_installed
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        aws s3 cp s3://bucket-ops-ssh/$line /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys --region eu-west-1
        chmod 600 /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chown $USER_NAME:$USER_NAME /home/$USER_NAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
      fi
    fi

  fi
done < ~/keys_retrieved_from_s3
```

Turns out that line `usermod -s /bin/false $USER_NAME` was causing the behaviour. Removing that line fixed the problem.

The `/bin/false` command is a login shell for many system accounts. Furthermore, at false is not the shell, but a command that does nothing and then also ends with a status code that signals an error. The result is what I have experienced; the user logs in and immediately sees the login prompt again.